# read.csv replaces column-name characters like `?` with `.`, `-` with `...`

Tags: r, rstudio, names, read.csv

I'm using RStudio and my output on the Console gets truncated.  I can't find how to stop the truncation (I tried searching `?options` as well as googling around for longer than I'd like to admit).

EDIT: My apologies everyone!  I originally had the long name as 'ThisIsAReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongName', but the issue only came up with the long name of 'Translation Service Info - Which translation service?'.  I think I found the issue.  The `...` wasn't truncating, it was replacing the unknown characters like `?` and `-` with `.` and `...`.

**Code**

```
# Load File
myfile <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\wliu\\Desktop\\myfile.csv",
               sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=2)

# Get my column names
mycolnames <- colnames(myfile)

# When I request a shorter name, this returns the full name
mycolnames[1]  # Assuming first col is a short name
[1] "ThisIsAShortName"

# However, when I request a longer name, this returns a truncated version
mycolnames[2]  # Assuming second col is a really long name
[1] "ThisIsA...Long...Name"
```

I want to get back the non-truncated version of `mycolnames[2]` (e.g. "ThisIsAReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongName")

**Setup**

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, RStudio Version 0.98.1091, R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport" with Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).  I tried with 'Use Git Bash as shell for Git projects' on and off.

**myfile.csv**

```
ThisIsAShortName, Translation Service Info - Which translation service?

23143505, Yes
23143614, No
23143324, Yes
```

[image: Char Replacement instead of truncating issue]

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the same result. e.g. `names(data.frame(ThisIsAReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongName=1:10))` returns the untruncated name

Comment: @Will Though, I can't test it (as I don't have Rstudio), are you using recent versions of Rstudio.

Comment: I'm on RStudio Version 0.98.1091 (latest version when I check for updates) and Windows 7 64bit

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce on Mac Version 0.98.1091

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. Can you include the column name as it is actually stored in the file (e.g., a small excerpt of `myfile.csv`)?

Comment: Is the name definitely being truncated - ie are there special characters in the names that are getting converted to dots when the data is read in?

Comment: Thanks for all the troubleshooting everyone.  It ended up being special characters that converted to dots (I didn't realize this so I gave a bad example of the dataset).  If someone places this as an answer, I'd happily accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: `read.csv` has the not-so-helpful default `check.names=TRUE`, which causes this name mangling on select characters (into legal R variable names) unless you turn it off. RStudio had nothing to do with it. Always try to repro on command-line R, so you can eliminate RStudio being the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior by `read.csv`, not a truncation problem in R. When you have spaces and special characters in the column names of a file, `read.csv` replaces each of them with a `.` unless you specify `check.names = FALSE`

Here's a glimpse at `make.names`, which is how `read.table` produces the column names.

```
nm <- "Translation Service Info - Which translation service?"
make.names(nm)
# [1] "Translation.Service.Info...Which.translation.service."
```

And here's the relevant line from `read.table`

```
if (check.names) 
        col.names <- make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

In RStudio, use the menu:

`Tools > Global Options > Code > Display`

In the Console section, set `Limit length of lines displayed in console to:` to some number much larger than it currently is set to.

Click OK.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
options(width=300)
```

Does that solve the issue?

Comment: The issue ended up being special characters for my particular file.  I gave a bad example (sorry) that I later edited when I realized my mistake.  I'll upvote this since it would solve the truncation issue for a normal file.